# exiftool: how to get mp3 tag value without key?

Tags: exiftool

I can read my mp3's `Title` metadata with:

```
$ exiftool -Title 1.mp3
Title                           : Foo
```

But how to get `Foo` only ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ exiftool -s -s -s -Title 1.mp3
Foo
```